# How to aggregate Sales by type in the below scenario

Tags: sql, oracle

In this scenario ,i have four tables as :

1. `T_SALES` has columns like

   ```
    CUST_KEY,
    ITEM_KEY,
    SALE_DATE,
    SALES_DLR
   ```
2. `T_ITEM` has columns like

   ```
    ITEM_KEY
    ITEM_NUM
    ITEM_TYPE_ID
   ```
3. `T_ITM_MP_RLT` has columns like

   ```
    ITEM_KEY
    MKT_PROG_KEY
   ```
4. `T_MKT_PROG` has columns like

   ```
    MKT_PROG_KEY
    MKT_PROG_CDE
   ```

now, i need to carry out the below logic in sql :

For all Items belonging to Item `Type = ‘RX’ and for the month of May 2012`
 `IF Marketing Program Code = 1 or 2
Aggregate Sales as Retail Program Sales
ELSE
IF Marketing Program Code = 4 or 7
Aggregate Sales as Hospital Program Sales
ELSE
Aggregate Sales as Acute Program Sales
END
END`

Comment: Can you add a little bit more information? What are the field type? What column does Item Type correspond to? What have you tried so far? In sql, aggregate functions cover a bunch of different functions. I assume by your use of aggregate in the question, you are referring to sum?

Comment: Hi ,ITEM_TYPE refers to ITEM_TYPE_ID which is alphanumeric.and the aggregate i am referring is SUM() corresponding to the column SALES_DLR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `ITEM_KEY` is a PK in `T_ITEM` and a FK somewhere else, and `MKT_PROG_KEY` is a PK for `T_MKT_PROG` and a FK somewhere else:

```
select I.ITEM_KEY, I.ITEM_NUM, I.ITEM_TYPE_ID, M.MKT_PROG_CDE,
       sum(S.SALES_DLR) SALES_AMOUNT,
       case when M.MKT_PROG_CDE in (1, 2) then 'Retail Program Sales'
            when M.MKT_PROG_CDE in (4, 7) then 'Hospital Program Sales'
            else 'Acute Program Sales'
            end label
from T_SALES S, T_ITEM I, T_ITM_MP_RLT R, T_MKT_PROG P
where trunc(S.SALE_DATE, 'MON') = '01 May 2012'
  and I.ITEM_KEY = S.ITEM_KEY
  and I.ITEM_TYPE_ID = 'RX'
  and R.ITEM_KEY = I.ITEM_KEY
  and P.MKT_PROG_KEY = R.MKT_PROG_KEY
group by I.ITEM_KEY, I.ITEM_NUM, I.ITEM_TYPE_ID, M.MKT_PROG_CDE
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
select 
    case 
    when mkt_prog_cde in (1,2) then 'Retail Program Sales' 
    when mkt_prog_cde in (4,7) then 'Hospital Program Sales' 
    else 'Acute Program Sales'
    end as SalesType,
    sum(sales_dlr) as SalesTotal
from t_sales inner join t_item on t_item.item_key = t_sales.item_key
inner join t_itm_mp_rlt on t_itm_mp_rlt = t_item.item_key
inner join t_mkt_prog on t_mkt_prog.mkt_prog_key = t_itm_mp_rlt.mkt_prog_key
where t_item.item_type_id = X -- you need to add the join or lookup for item_type='RX' here
group by 
    case 
    when mkt_prog_cde in (1,2) then 'Retail Program Sales' 
    when mkt_prog_cde in (4,7) then 'Hospital Program Sales' 
    else 'Acute Program Sales'
    end
```